# Yii UrlManager and multiple Get parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, yii

I have a problem with my Yii urlManager. I'm using the path format and want to pass multiple get variables. The url looks like that:

```
/Yii/app/de/user/admin/id/5/test/hello
```

my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteBase /Yii/app/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I tried with the urlManager, but it doesn't work with following rules:

```
'rules' => array(
    '<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
)
```

The $_GET should look like this:

```
array(3) { 
    ["/de/user/admin"]=> string(0) ""
    ["id"]=> string(1) "5" 
    ["test"]=> string(5) "hello" 
    ["language"]=> string(2) "de" 
}
```

It musst work for a variable nummber of get parameters. For example:

If you sort by an CGridView by using ajax, the nummber of parameters are different.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the url manager for this.

Your variables will be passed to the action like:

```
www.yourdomain.com/yourController/yourAction?id=5&test=hello&language=de
```

and this is your action function in yourController

```
public function yourAction($id, $test, $language){
  //$id is 5
  //$test is 'hello'
  //$language is 'de'
}
```

Comment: but what if you want to make use of URL Manager to "prettify" the URL. I don't want the ? and the parameter names and the = in my URL. I would like the URL to look like: www.yourdomain.com/yourController/yourAction/5/hello/de and I want URL Manager to map URL components to GET parameters

Comment: I am sorry. I am way too long out of this - but you could ask a new question and refer to this one.